# PHP XML xlink:href Attributes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm having trouble reading attributes from the Spreadshirt API with SimpleXML. I can't grab the xlink:href attribute from resources, which is what I need as it's not displays in the data received. Seem to be able to grab everything else, though.

This is the XML I'm reading in:

```
 <articles xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://api.spreadshirt.net" xlink:href="http://api.spreadshirt.net/api/v1/shops/800323/articles?fullData=true" offset="0" limit="50" count="16" sortField="default" sortOrder="default">
    <article isDuplicate="false" xlink:href="http://api.spreadshirt.net/api/v1/shops/800323/articles/100402428" id="100402428">
      <name>Hammer T-Shirt</name>
      <price>
        <vatExcluded>13.33</vatExcluded>
        <vatIncluded>16.00</vatIncluded>
        <vat>20.00</vat>
        <currency xlink:href="http://api.spreadshirt.net/api/v1/currencies/2" id="2"/>
      </price>
      <resources>
        <resource mediaType="png" type="preview" xlink:href="http://image.spreadshirt.net/image-server/v1/products/125642560/views/1"/>
      </resources>
    </article>
 </atricles>
```

This is the data coming back from SimpleXML:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [isDuplicate] => false
        [id] => 27368595
    )

[name] => Hammer Boxers
[price] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [vatExcluded] => 10.00
        [vatIncluded] => 12.00
        [vat] => 20.00
        [currency] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                    )

            )

    )

[resources] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [resource] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [mediaType] => png
                        [type] => preview
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm stumped.

Comment: You don't display the data that comes back. To display the data, use the `->asXML('php://output')` method on the **SimpleXMLElement** object, do not use `print_r` or `var_dump`, these functions hide data of any object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `isDuplicate` and `id` attributes are in the same namespace as the element.

The `href` element is in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink` namespace, as indicated by the `xlink` prefix that is registered on the `<articles>` root element.

To access all the elements for the namespace, call `$element->attributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')`.

The idea is that the root element could instead say `xmlns:foobar="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`, and each `<article>` would have `foobar:href="..."` attributes, and the code above would still work, because the bound prefix is just a way of improving readability. What counts is the namespace URL, not its prefix.